# How to use Java streams to map items

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to Java and started learning about `java streams`. I have understood `filter`ation using streams however, understanding `map` is becoming a challenge.

I have a `Person.java` code

```
public class Person {

    // Fields
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String gender;

    // Constructor
    public Person( String name,  int age,  String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    // Getters
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

}
```

and `Streams.java` as

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class Streams {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List <Person> people = getPeople();

        // Map
        System.out.println("Map using Streams | Increase Everyone's Age by 10:");
        List <Person> persons = people.stream()
            // this part is failing
            .map(person -> person.setAge(person.getAge() + 10))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()
        );
        persons.forEach(
            person ->
            System.out.printf("%s: %d\n", person.getName(), person.getAge())
        );

    }

    private static List<Person> getPeople() {
        return List.of(
            new Person("Female-Kid", 10, "female"),
            new Person("Male-Young", 21, "male"),
            new Person("Male-Mid", 34, "male"),
            new Person("Female-Old", 100, "female")
        );
    }
}
```

In above code, I have a list `<Person>` and I want to increase everyone's age by 10, however above code is failing and is not correct.

Could someone let me know the correct implementation.

Cheers,
DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `Stream.map()` accepts the instance of `Function` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-). The problem is that most likely `person.setAge()` returns `void`, and therefore [`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html) (Java most famous compiler, most likely you are using it), that is trying to infer the exact [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) being used in lambda, cannot infer `Function`, since `setAge` returns `void`. In order to fix it, make `setAge` return this, such as:

```
public Person setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
    return this;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
As noted in the comments, in your exact scenario usage of `map()` is not recommended. You can just use `forEach()` that accepts the `Consumer`.

Comment: I want to accept the answer however, SO is not letting me because I can not accept the answer just in 2 mins, thanks for your lightning fast answer. Will accept it later.

Comment: This answer will work, but for the sake of your code's readability, please do not actually do this. The point of `Stream.map()` is to turn a bunch of A's into a bunch of B's. When people see `Stream.map`, that's what they'll be expecting; by breaking that expectation, you'll make it harder to read and understand your code.  Here you're not turning each `Person` into anything new: you're just modifying it. That's what `Stream.forEach` is for — or even just a simple `for` loop.

Comment: To second @yshavit, think about what happens when the stream’s terminal operation is not `collect` but `findFirst` or even worse, `count()`.

Comment: I agree with you both @Holger, @yshavit, I just noted how the map can be changed to satisfy the requirements. But `forEach` would of course suit better, I agree

Answer (score 8):

It would be more appropriate to use the `forEach` method here rather than `map`. Map is for transforming one piece of data into another, forEach is for doing an operation on each element of the stream which is what's happening here.

Comment: Yes, however, in the given example, the List returned will be the unmodifiable list from List.of(). And will not support modification of the original list (no new items or no removals) in this case OP might want to create a new list and modify the elements at the same time, thus the stream. Though in other cases, if we know beforehand it is not an immutable list, then you would be right

Comment: @BIBOOunit1998X OP's code isn't trying to modify the List at all: `people` and `persons` will contain exactly the same elements, in the same order (if they go with the accepted answer, of having the setter just `return this`). An unmodifiable list _does_ still let you call methods on the elements of the list that modify their state.

Comment: I know OP's code isnt modifying the list, I may have not conveyed my meaning properly, but I m saying in case OP wants to modify the list later streaming and collecting to list might be a possible use case, but if OP didnt use List.of() from the start, I would definitely use foreach. @yshavit

Comment: @BIBOOunit1998X Ah, gotcha. Though in that case, they should probably collect it to an ArrayList specifically: `Collectors.toList()` [doesn't make any guarantee as to mutability of the list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()), and I _think_ OpenJDK's implementation happens to be unmodifiable (though it's been a while since I've actually used it, so I may be mistaken on that).

Comment: Addendum: using `map` would be appropriate when using an immutable `Person` type and a function creating a new `Person` instance with the changed age.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution use the following code,

```
List <Person> persons = people.stream()
            .map(person -> {person.setAge(person.getAge() + 10); return person;})
            .collect(Collectors.toList()
        );
```

The setAge() method has a return type of void, which java does not like when you use with the map() operation

Answer (score 1):

you can use forEach or peek.

```java
List<Person> persons = people.stream()
        .peek(person -> person.setAge(person.getAge() + 10))
        .toList();
```

```java
people.forEach(person -> person.setAge(person.getAge() + 10));
```

Comment: Abusing `peek` for such an operation is not recommended. It does not guaranty to process all elements, as its purpose is to allow debugging which elements are processed *by the actual operation*. Try what happens when the stream’s terminal operation is not `collect` but `findFirst` or `count()`. Or compare the result when using `count()` in Java 8 and in newer versions…